# Are there verses in the qur'an on which there's no consensus about the addressed gender?

Tags: quran, tafseer, men-women, uloom-al-quran

I'd like to know if there are verses in the qur'an where it is seemingly unclear whether the verse addresses both women and men or only one of both genders and on which at least some scholars apparently hold different views.

Quoting both the verse(s) and the different views would be appreciated.